# Setting and changing MetaInformation for arbitrary objects

Tags: metadata, time-series

I work with a lot of dynamic data in `{{date, datum}. . .}` format,

```
datedatalist={{{2001, 1, 1}, 45.2}, {{2002, 1, 1}, 132.}, {{2003, 1, 2}, 121.1}};
```

and I have historically attached a header to each object in a format like

```
datedataObject={{header version, data series name, type (value, % change, etc.)}, datedatalist};
```

I can see advantages to using Mathematica's TemporalData[] type, and to using MetaInformation[] for recording the header. I would set this up with something like

```
newObject = TemporalData[datedatalist, MetaInformation -> {"name" -> "whatever", "type" -> "value"}];
```

and extract header items with, for example

```
newObject["name"]
```

But this leaves me with two puzzles,

1. How do I add MetaInformation after the object has been created? and
2. How do I change existing MetaInformation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about this?

Load your sample data

```
datedatalist={{{2001, 1, 1}, 45.2}, {{2002, 1, 1}, 132.}, {{2003, 1, 2}, 121.1}};
ct = TemporalData[datedatalist, MetaInformation -> {"name" -> "whatever", "type" -> "value"}];
```

Modify its meta information

```
ct=TemporalData[ct, MetaInformation->{"name"->"Johnny", "fat"->True}];
ct["MetaInformation"]
(* {"name" -> "Johnny", "fat" -> True, "type" -> "value"} *)
```

Comment: Very nice. How did you figure that out?

Comment: @MichaelStern luck. I just felt it was sensible for nested temporal data's to be flattened out, tried it and worked.

Comment: To make this more general I would suggest to use the information contained in the first part of the `TemporalData` object. For example, `addMetaInformation[ td_, metarules_ ] := Which[ td[[1]] === TimeSeries, TimeSeries[ td, MetaInformation -> metarules], ...=== EventSeries,  EventSeries[...], True, TemporalData[ td, MetaInformation -> metarules ]`. Also one might define `addMetaInformation[ td_, None] := td /. (MetaInformation -> _) :> Sequence[]`.

Answer (score 3):

I sure hope there is a cleaner way to get both tasks than the following which is based on accessing and changing `Part`s of a temporal data object:

```
 s = Accumulate[
 RandomInteger[{-5, 1}, 10]~Join~RandomInteger[{-1, 5}, 10]]; 
 td = TemporalData[s, {1, 20}];
 td["Properties"]
(* {"Part","Path","PathComponents","PathCount","PathFunction",
   "PathFunctions","PathLengths","Paths","PathStates","PathTimes",
   "Properties","SliceData","SliceDistribution","StateDimensions",
    "States","Times"} *)
```

Add `MetaInformation`:

```
 td[[2, -1]] = AppendTo[td[[2, -1]], MetaInformation -> {"Event" -> 10}];
 td["Properties"]
 (* {"Event","Part","Path","PathComponents","PathCount","PathFunction",
    "PathFunctions","PathLengths","Paths","PathStates","PathTimes",
    "Properties","SliceData","SliceDistribution","StateDimensions",
    "States","Times"} *)

 td["Event"]
 (* 10 *)
```

Change the value of a `MetaInformation` element:

```
 d[[2, -1, 1, 2, 1, 2]] = 20;
 td["Event"]
 (* 20 *)
```

Add another `MetaInformation` element:

```
 td[[2, -1, 1, 2]] = AppendTo[td[[2, -1, 1, 2]], "name" -> "abc"];  
 td["MetaInformation"]
 (*{"Event" -> 20,"name" ->"abc"} *)
 td["name"]
 (* "abc" *)
```

Note: This approach works in version 9.0.1.0. Version 10 seems to have quite a few new features related to `TemporalData`. However, documentation information related to `MetaInformation` has not changed.

Comment: This works in V10, not in V9: `td = TemporalData[td, "MetaInformation" -> {"Event" -> 20}]`

Comment: @MichaelE2, right. `MetaInformation->..." (without string quotes) also works in Version 10. Although documentation on `MetaInformation` says the values can be changed using `SetOptions` it does not work for `TemporalData`. And, although `MetaInformation` is listed as an `Option` for `TemporalData`, `Options[td]` gives `{}`; and one needs to use `td["Options"]` to get `MetaInformation -> {...}`.

Comment: Yes, the quotes were a typo that happened to work.

Comment: I think the ultimate solution will have to come from Wolfram, but I appreciate the kludge in the meantime.

Answer (score 2):

David Reiss came up with a nice kludge over in the Wolfram Communities --

```
newObject = newObject /. {("name" -> _) :> ("name" -> "Happy feet")}
```

changes the "name" part of the MetaInformation in newObject. And

```
newObject = 
 newObject /. {(MetaInformation -> x_) :> (MetaInformation -> Flatten[{x, "another" -> "Something"}])}
```

adds the "another" -> "Something" rule to the MetaInformation of newObject.

This does seem like a bug in Mathematica though; the behavior is illogical and at odds with the documentation.

Comment: Seems to me that if designed "properly" it should work with `SetOptions` and also probably `CurrentValue` (analogous to how `TaggingRules` works). I wonder if this is a bug or intentional? Have you asked tech support about this?

Comment: I reported this as a bug. They haven't responded, but I don't think I ever get responses to bug reports.

Comment: They never use the word "bug" but normally I get a reply saying that it has been forwarded to developers and I'll be emailed when an update occurs ...or words to that effect.

Comment: I had an exchange with tech support and provided them with a detailed notebook. They have "reported this issue into [their] database."

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch Hah. Tech support says that this behavior is "by design." I asked them to record it as a bug anyway.

Comment: WTF!  So they are now designing things that are broken???

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch I think the tech support person may not have been one of Wolfram's best. With any luck, my example notebook will filter through to a developer.